# How to solve undefined references, is the library not imported, or other problems

Tags: win32gui

I'm trying to use Win32 GUI project on a project, but when I compile it, I get a lot of undefined reference errors.

> ||=== Build: Debug in 05.9.finally (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   obj\Debug\main.o||In function `Z4OpenP6HWND__':|
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\计算机图形\05.9.finally\main.cpp|61|undefined
>   reference to`wglCreateContext@4'|
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\计算机图形\05.9.finally\main.cpp|63|undefined
>   reference to `wglMakeCurrent@8'|
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\计算机图形\05.9.finally\main.cpp|65|undefined
>   reference to`glClearColor@16'| obj\Debug\main.o||In function
>   `Z4Initv':|
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\计算机图形\05.9.finally\main.cpp|76|undefined
>   reference to`glBlendFunc@8'|
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\计算机图形\05.9.finally\main.cpp|77|undefined
>   reference to `glClearColor@16'|
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\计算机图形\05.9.finally\main.cpp|78|undefined
>   reference to`glClearDepth@8'|
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\计算机图形\05.9.finally\main.cpp|79|undefined
>   reference to `glDepthFunc@4'|
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\计算机图形\05.9.finally\main.cpp|80|undefined
>   reference to`glEnable@4'|
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\计算机图形\05.9.finally\main.cpp|81|undefined
>   reference to `glShadeModel@4'|
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\计算机图形\05.9.finally\main.cpp|82|undefined
>   reference to`glHint@8'| obj\Debug\main.o||In function `Z6Draw3Dv':|

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <windows.h>
GLfloat step = 0.0f;

HINSTANCE hInstance;                                         // 系统实例句柄
HWND      hWndMain;                                          // 主窗体句柄
HWND      hWnd;                                              // 窗体句柄变量定义
HDC       hDC;                                               // 设备描述表变量定义
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;                                   // 像素格式结构变量定义
HGLRC     hGLRC;                                             // OpenGL渲染描述表变量定义

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);        // 窗体过程函数声明

GLboolean keys[256];
GLfloat rotStep = 30.0f;
void keyPress();


GLuint Open(HWND phWnd)

{
      hWnd = phWnd;

      hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

      pfd.dwDamageMask    = 0;                       // 忽略层遮罩

      int pixelformat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);

      SetPixelFormat(hDC, pixelformat, &pfd);

      hGLRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);

      wglMakeCurrent(hDC,hGLRC);

      glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);          // 初始化背景为灰色

      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You includes have a forward slash in the naming. Maybe you wanted #include "path/name".

Comment: I tried what you said, but it didn't work.However, in the same engineering environment, OpenGL project can work.

Comment: OpenGL uses the same header

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have solved it by now; in case not then you can try providing correct library path. Use command line options `-L` for path to library folder and `-l` for library name while compiling/linking.

An online lookup for OpenGL suggests the library file names may be any or all from these: `opengl32.a or opengl32.lib`, `glu32.a or glu32.lib`, `freeglut.a or freeglut.lib`  (choose `.a` if you are building on Linux or `.lib` on Windows).